# Buttons responsive with the background image

Tags: css, image, button, background, responsive

right now I'm working in Magento 2. I'm having a problem that the background image with the buttons doesn't stay the same when I'm resizing in google chrome.

```css
.botones1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #357b2b !important;
}

.botones1:hover {
    background-color: #9FCD4C !important;
}

.botones2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 796px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #357b2b !important;
}

.botones2:hover {
    background-color: #9FCD4C !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/any" alt="Smiley face">
        <a class="button botones1" href="#">Buy Coupon</a> 
        <a class="button botones2" href="#">Sell Coupon</a>
</div>
```

When I enter with a mobile device I want the background image, and the buttons are resized in a responsive way and I want them to stay in the same place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your page responsive, you should use Flexbox & Grid to position you elements instead of pixels, bc they will limit you massively. You could try to use display:flex for the `<div>` and arrange your elements in the flex container (try to play around with the Inspector).

Here's some good stuff about flexbox: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Grid: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/